# $cookies not working in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I want to keep user login status even refresh the browser. But I find a problem when I apply $cookies in angularjs. Following is my code:

```
function signIn() {
    var params = {email: vm.email, password: vm.password};
    Service.authBuffer = _.extend(Service.authBuffer, params);
    $.ajax({
        type:      'POST',
        url:       GetEndpointUrl('/api/auth/login'),
        dataType:  "jsonp",
        data:      params,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("login data", data);
            $scope.safeApply(function() {
                Service.authBuffer = _.extend(Service.authBuffer, data);
                console.log("login auth data", Service.authBuffer);
                $location.path('/task');
                var cookieExp = new Date();
                cookieExp.setDate(cookieExp.getDate() + 7);
                $cookies.put('Service.authBuffer', Service.authBuffer.email, { expires: cookieExp });
            })            
        }
    })     
}
```

So I am wondering how to change the code to make $cookies work.

Comment: cookie has save only limited size data. check your data size

Answer (score 0):

You probably have not injected the ngCookies module. Use something like this

```
angular.module('cookiesExample', ['ngCookies'])

.controller('ExampleController', ['$cookies', function($cookies) {
  // Retrieving a cookie
  var favoriteCookie = $cookies.get('myFavorite');
  // Setting a cookie
  $cookies.put('myFavorite', 'oatmeal');
}]);
```

[Reference Link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies)

Answer (score 0):

Answer few of this questions to get better understanding of the problem:
- please provide the error message you get in console log of browser
- have you included angular-cookies library?
- have you injected ngCookies in app module?
- have you injected $cookies in controller?